# Reduce ListView height when there are fewer items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget, android-wrap-content

I have ListView to be used in the app widget.
The list view has a fixed height of some 140 dp to accommodate 3 items, now when there is only one item to show, there is space left below the item.
I want to be able to set the list view like this -
set wrap_content and a maximum height.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

when you use fixed height it will always take that height no matter how many items u have.
In that case u can use maxHeight and set it to 140 dp.So when u have less item the height will reduce. If u have shared the code and a image it would have been better.

Comment: max_height is not working here.
Just pitting wrap_content worked for me.